# How do I browse and edit WinRM configuration settings?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, winrm

I'd like to browse and edit WinRM configuration settings but struggle with `winrm.exe`.

Is there an alternative app, a command line switch, XML file, registry setting (etc) that I should investigate?

Comment: Related [Security Checklist for configuring WinRM on servers](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/11613/396)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinRM is not very friendly. You can browse the settings easily enough:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782312%28WS.10%29.aspx

That describes some of the details, but `winrm get wsman:microsoft.com/wsman/2005/06/config -format:#xml` will dump out an XML-formatted file for you to use.

Unfortunately, you can't `put` the whole file. That would be easy. Instead, you can put individual lines you want to change

```
winrm get wsman:microsoft.com/wsman/2005/06/config/Listener?IP=10.1.2.3+Port=443 @{Hostname=myhost.example.com}
```

Where IP, and Port are selectors to pick the right Listener section, and Hostname is the value being changed.

Comment: How/where did you learn this?  Where can I get more information?  Are there API's I can use (via Managed or unmanaged code?)

Comment: @makerofthings7 If you're looking for programatic access to WinRM, try [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).